# How to get class members without having access to Class type

Tags: c#, types, reflection

I have a class (Plug_Comment) with properties which is passed as a member of another class (m_Descriptor)
[image]

I can also get the type

[image]

[image]

Inside I can see the property I need (useless) which is a double

[image]

but I can't get to it for the type Plug_Comment is not known here so I can't cast it.

-----EDIT----

I will try to explain that again. Sorry for not having made it clear.

I want to access a member of a class.
The class type is Plug_Comment.Cplug_Comment and the member name is double useless which in turn is inside the class properties;
[image]

So namespace = Plug_Comment with inside the class Plugin_Comment, inside the class Properties and inside the member **double useless** wihch is what I want.

Then, from another part of the code I get the aforementioned properties but casted into an object (see above).  From there the Namespace Plug_Comment is not visible. So all what I have is the object and I can't cast it to Plug_Comment.PluginComment.Properties.

[image]

That being said visual studio show clearly (See picture) that this object is of type Plug_Comment.properties.

This is why I am trying to use reflection. Reflection or not how can I get to the double useless?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking here. I don't even know why you are trying to use reflection and messing around with the types.

Comment: Agree with @DavidG. Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code together with an explanation of what you are trying to achieve. Screenshots are not ideal.

Comment: I don't have any clue what you are doing...  What is `m_Descriptor`? How and where is it declared? Why do you try to cast to a non-existent type `Plug_Comment.CPlug_Comment.properties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in m_Descriptor.Properties.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    if (item.Name.Contains("useless"))
    {
        double myUseless = System.Convert.ToDouble (item.GetValue(m_Descriptor.Properties));
    }
}
```

you iterate on all fields (1 in your case) and when the name is correct you get the value

Answer (score 0):

> I have a class (Plug_Comment)

You do not have a Plug_Comment class. Based on your screenshot, Plug_Comment is a namespace. It contains two classes; the `CPlug_Comment` class and the `properties` class. The `properties` class contains a property called `useless`.

To access a property called `useless` that belongs to a class called `properties` that sits in the namespace `Plug_Comment`, you can do it like so (the example includes creating an instance of the class `properties`):

```
using Plug_Comment;

var instanceOfProperties = new properties();
double uselessValue = instanceOfProperties.useless;
```

And here's an example based on the very first screenshot in your question:

```
var a = m_Descriptor.Properties.useless;
```

Comment: I can't put using Plug_Comment for I can't see it

Answer (score 0):

> Я также могу получить тип
> [image]

From this we can conclude that the variable `a` is of type `properties` in the `Plug_Comment` namespace.

Therefore, the variable can be cast to this type:

```cs
Plug_Comment.properties prps = (Plug_Comment.properties) a;
```

Or:

```cs
using Plug_Comment;

     properties prps = (properties) a;
```

After such casting, all public members of the "properties" type will become available to you.
You can get and set values ​​for properties, call methods.

```cs
double num = prps.useless;
prps.useless = 123.456;
```

The compiler can generate an error on such a cast if the "properties" type is private or internal.
If there is that error, show its full text.
And in this case, you will have to use reflection to work with a non-public class.